# Are $(2,28)$ and $(5,3207)$ the only solutions $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, products, square-numbers

I noticed something as I was playing around with prime numbers. By denoting $p_i$ the $i^{\text{th}}$ prime number, I discovered the following:

$$
\begin{align}\prod_{i=1}^2\left(p_i^{ \ 2}+i\right)&= 28^2-27^2 \\ \prod_{i=1}^5\left(p_i^{ \ 2}+i\right)&=3207^2-27^2.\end{align}
$$

Given the general equation

> $$\prod_{i=1}^m\left(p_i^{ \ 2}+i\right)=n^2-27^2\tag*{$\big(\left(m,n\right)\in\mathbb{N}^2\big)$}$$

I have tested for $5< m\leqslant 32$ and it appears that for $m > 5$, there does not exist such $n$. I know that $n^2-27^2=(n+27)(n-27)$, but this does not help me make much progress.

Is this true? Can it be verified? Thus far, it remains a conjecture that the only solutions $(m,n)$ are $(2,28)$ and $(5,3207)$.

---

**Source of Testing:**

[$$\text{Alpertron $-$ Integer Factorization Calculator.}$$](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM)

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Verified for $m \leq 50000$.Though I am not sure if there is something special about this, since the squares are simply more and more rare when we go to bigger numbers, so it is just expected, kind of...

Comment: @Sil Wow!! That was quick! Thank you very much. Yes, I know, it is quite expected, but conjectures like [Catalan's Conjecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us-__MukH9I) is also expected (which is now a theorem, by the way). At the end of the day, really, you just never know... :)

Comment: True, though I have tried to replace $27^2$ with other numbers, not only squares, and it just basically never hits $n^2$, so that is suggesting to me it will be hard to prove by evaluating specific properties of $27^2$, and is more likely to do with probability of number being square. But yea, who knows :)

Comment: @Sil One of the things that fascinate me the most is that sometimes, the simplest assertions are the most difficult to prove! *Fermat's Last Theorem* is a great example :)

Comment: So, is it $(p_i^2+1)$ or $(p_i^2+i)$ in the general equation?

Comment: @rtybase it's $p_i^{ \ 2}+i$ in the general equation. hahah, my bad. Nice pickup. Ooohh, I hope **Sil** did not waste their time coding for the wrong equation.... :\

Comment: I can approve that upto $m=10^4$, no further solution exists. I am currently running the verification upto $m=10^5$

Comment: @Sil An even "easier" question : Are there infinite many primes of the form $n^2+1$, where $n$ is an integer ? This is an open problem!

Comment: Don't worry, it was with $i$ :) @Peter Yea, I am afraid number theory is full of those :S

Comment: No further solution upto $m=10^5$

Comment: @Peter thank you very much :)

Comment: @Sil oh thank goodness it was with an $i$, hahah :))

Comment: @PreservedFruit your edit does not really make much of a difference, so I don't mind. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Not that it helps answer the question, but $n^2-27^2$ may also be written $n^2-3^6$ if you find that prettier.